# Error while generating module in symfony1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

when i trying to create a module using the command `php symfony doctrine:generate-module --with-show --non-verbose-templates backend comment TicketComments` i am getting error like this

> The "TicketComments" model has no "ticket" relation.
>
> [?php use_stylesheets_for_form($form) ?]
>
> [?php use_javascripts_for_form($form) ?]

**this is my schema.yml file**

```
ticket:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: ticket
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    client_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    name:
      type: string(200)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    type:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    content:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    status:
      type: string(10)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    assigned_user_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    estimated_time:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    working_status:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    working_status_comment:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    attachments:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    posttime:
      type: string(150)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
TicketAttachments:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: ticket_attachments
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    ticket_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    name:
      type: string(200)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    ticket:
      local: ticket_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
TicketComments:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: ticket_comments
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    ticket_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    comment:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    file:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    post_date:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    ticket:
      local: ticket_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
```

any one please help me. thank you...

Comment: Which version of symfony / doctrine? I tried with a new project with your schema and every thing went fine.

Comment: @j0k i am using   symfony 1.4 and doctrine 1.2 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried renaming the ticket class in your schema ?
Currently it's "ticket", lowercase.  Try with "Ticket", and then rebuild your classes using:
symfony doctrine:build --all-classes

It may then create the missing relationship